# i have a error in webservice in php whit ios

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have this error:

> Optional("<html><body>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn\'t send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n")

and this:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

This is my code:

```
print("envar solicitud")

let url = URL(string: "http://dev.viupruebas.com.mx/webservice/service/prueba")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
request.httpMethod = "GET"
let postString = "usuario=empleadodemo&password=1234"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data else {//si existe un error se termina la funcion
        print("solicitud fallida \(error)")//manejamos el error
        return //rompemos el bloque de codigo
    }

    do {//creamos nuestro objeto json

        print("recibimos respuesta")

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("respuesta : \(responseString)")


        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: String] {
            print ("**respuesta = \(data)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {//proceso principal
               let nombre = json["username"]//constante
                let telefono = json["telefono"]//variable
              //  var pais = json["pais"]
               // self.nombreLabel.text = nombre//ponemos el texto en los textfield
              //  self.edadLabel.text = edad
                //self.paisLabel.text = pais
            }


        }


    } catch let parseError {//manejamos el error
        print("error al parsear: \(parseError)")
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("respuesta : \(responseString)")
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Please add more info: some details about the request, the HTTP response. It's hard for us to figure out what your problem is without these details.

Comment: @Alexis are you gone?:) There are many conversations here without you.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code. Made 1 change: changed `GET` to `POST`. This is the answer i receive now:

`**respuesta = ["pais": "Mexico Veracruz", "nombre": "Martin Flores", "edad": "30"]`

JSON is OK. Meaning that it did deserialization with no errors.

General advice: make sure the backend documentation is followed properly. Since this mistake could be avoided just by following the API doc. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Cristik have you read the question in full? He also has another issue as you may see. Also check the update3 of my answer please. I think the person who asked the question is doing something really strange and I can't get what it is. How can he get 2 errors at the same time?

Comment: yes i have the correctly respond but i did change my file  "Post" for Get

Comment: I see. so you just don't want to put -1 back, right?:) I solved the problem. I agree that question is bad. But man why do you put -1? Do you think you gonna grow StackOverflow this way?

Comment: @AlexisOsorio can you please elaborate? what do you mean?

Comment: yes, the answer is correctly @TungFam  :) thank you but i need send the params whith GET, but with Post works

Comment: @Cristik to be honest I don't understand you:) changing GET to POST gives the correct answer. even json code is good. i checked it and all works. what is the problem with my answer ????

Comment: @AlexisOsorio why do you need to use "GET"?:) Post works with parameters. You can't post parameters using GET as far as I know (if the backend is not a magic there).

Comment: @Cristik agree. edited my answer :) even before reading your comment hehe:)

Comment: "you need to do this in order to solve that" -- meaning to provide a more general answer? but not local? @Cristik

Comment: I see. Added the general advice. thanks for sharing and explaining! @Cristik

Comment: @AlexisOsorio is the problem solved? if not please update.